# trying to insert character in the index of a string

Tags: python, string

i'm tring to insert 0 if hours are in single number(04) or if hours are in 24hours format then it should not be changed. I'm new to python. plz guide me.

```
current_time = '08:00'
lst = ['00:00','04:00','08:00','12:00','16:00','20:00']
if current_time in lst:
    hour, minute = current_time.split(':')
    if hour == '00':
        hour = '24'
    start_hour = int(hour)-4
    start_time = str(start_hour)+':'+'00'
    end_hour = int(hour)-1
    end_time = str(end_hour)+':'+'59'
    print(start_time,end_time)
```

I'm getting output like this:

```
4:00 7:59
```

but I'm expecting output like this

```
04:00 07:59
```

i've tried below approach

```
if len(start_time[0])==1:
    start_time = start_time[:0]+'0'+start_time[0:]

output:
016:00
```

Comment: The exact issue that you have is unclear, you should have a look at `zfill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it with [zfill](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp):

```
current_time = '08:00'
lst = ['00:00','04:00','08:00','12:00','16:00','20:00']
if current_time in lst:
    hour, minute = current_time.split(':')
    if hour == '00':
        hour = '24'
    start_hour = int(hour)-4
    start_time = str(start_hour).zfill(2)+':'+'00'
    end_hour = int(hour)-1
    end_time = str(end_hour).zfill(2)+':'+'59'
    print(start_time,end_time)
```

Result:

```
04:00 07:59
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use python f-strings, code likes below

```
start_time = f'{start_hour:02d}:00'
end_time = f'{end_hour:02d}:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already function [`rjust(width, fillchar)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) built in Python, which will add padding to your string. Just change `start_time = str(start_hour)+':'+'00'` to `start_time = str(start_hour).rjust(2, '0')+':'+'00'` and it will add missing zero if needed.